How to recover an ABP2 sensor with "internal math saturation" flag active
I have a custom board with a ABP2 pressure sensor, a ABP2LANT060PG2A3XX with 60 psi maximum range.
The communication is fine, I can send the measure command and read back the results, apparently with no errors.
After some successfully tests, it happened that the sensors began to read 0 psi.
I checked the status byte and it was 65 (0x41).
From the datasheet I learn the 0x01 bit means:

internal math saturation has occurred

I'm pretty sure I didn't exceed the maximum value (60 psi ~ 4.14 bar) since my pump can achieve only 2 bar.
The odd thing is even disconnecting the pressure port and power cycle the sensor, it still return 0x41 for status byte.
In the datasheet and in the application notes I cannot find an explanation of what this flag actually means and how to recover after it is set high.

Have you tried speaking with Honeywell?

@Andyaka yes, I'm waiting an answer. But perhaps is a dumb question and somebody here can help me.
